# Need multiple iPads to communicate with each other

Tags: ios, ipad, p2p

We are building an iPad App for an enterprise scenario.   Users will be using the iPads to check in guests at special corporate events.   There could be as many as a dozen iPads used for check-ins and they all need to have accurate data on who has been checked in, when and any notes that have been entered.  The catch is that there will often be no internet access.   So the iPads must be able to communicate with each other.   All iPads will be at one location, but they could be as far as 100-300 feet apart.   I suppose we can include a requirement that users need to periodically move close to each other if the distance is too far.

We are open to either a peer-to-peer solution where by the iPads actually talk to each other, or we can have a central laptop which acts as a server and the iPads all talk to the server.   Any thoughts on how this can be done, what the options are, if we need to establish a wifi network, etc., etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are 4G iPads not an option to circumvent the lack of Internet? Then you can have a normal hosted server / API and be done with it.

Comment: Why not setup an adhoc WiFi network with a central computer? You don't need Internet access, just some WiFi gear.

Comment: If neither David or rmaddy's suggestions work for you, you should look into GameKit and its peer-to-peer networking capability over WiFi or BT. I would go for one of their solutions first, though !

Answer (score 3):

Since you are open to a central laptop, I would go with that and a WiFi base station that all of the iPads attach to.

Then you could have a simple server that is told when a user checks in on an iPad, and stores that in a database - if someone tries to check in again it would be easy to issue a response that the person had already been checked in.

As a backup, or instead of the server you could use Gamekit with a hosted match (unlimited devices) - as long as all of the iPads are on the same network they should be able to see each other.  Then you could broadcast to all participants when someone had been checked in so that other devices would hold that info locally.  It would probably be more problematic than the server but also possibly more robust.

In either case make sure that all possible error conditions (like total failure of network or server or ability to connect to other iPads) leave the iPad in a state where they can still check in guests, store who has been checked in and simply broadcast up the data when service resumes.  You do NOT want guests that have a wait because of a network glitch!

Comment: +1: I like this answer. However, I personally wouldn't bother with broadcasting each check in. Instead, you could just ask the server for all check-ins (setup and call an API to get all check-ins) whenever you needed such. Perhaps you might also have the server return a `good` or `error` response whenever an iPad attempts to check a user in- with one of the `errors` being that the user is already checked in? This seems like a better lazy-load strategy to me and likely would require less programming effort.

Comment: The least effort the better is probably a great approach!  But I would spend some extra effort on some kind of redundancy if possible because I just KNOW that a server running on a laptop at an event will fail somehow, technical reasons being only a tiny part of the possible universe of failure.